# Register to/register for or register from?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Let's say there are multiple test centers to choose from, but one is different from the rest because it has **freebies** to offer only to **registered clients**. Assuming a friend has just given you that tip, and he says:

> "You can get free review materials when you register **to/for/from** their test center."

Which is the correct preposition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, it's probably register 'with'.

You register **for** an activity

> I want to register for the 10k race next weekend.

You register **with** an organization.

> Since I'm 18, I have to register with the draft board.

You might register **with** the organization **at** a particular location.

> I'm going to register with the voting commission.  I think I can do that either at their main county office or at the town hall.

In your example:

> You can get free review materials when you register with their test center.
>
> Can I do that online?
>
> No, you have to do it at the test center itself.